# VBA - invoke method of native object without type information (e.g. call IUnknown::Release)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm invoking a few native functions via VBA, which at times return pointers to certain objects. For example, I'm calling CreateStreamOnHGlobal(), which would return a pointer to an IStream interface.

But - is there any way in VBA to call a method of this object? For example, when I'm done using that, I would like to release the stream via a call to IUnknown::Release. Given I don't have any type information whatsoever though, I can't do that directly.

```
Declare Function CreateStreamOnHGlobal Lib "ole32" (ByVal hGlobal As LongPtr, ByVal fDeleteOnRelease As Long, ppstm As Any) As Long
Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal uFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long

Const GMEM_MOVEABLE = &H2

Sub test()
  Dim pMem, pStream AS LongPtr

  pMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE,0)
  CreateStreamOnHGlobal(pMem, 1, pStream)

  ' .. do stuff with the stream ..

  ' now call .Release() on the IStream object pointed to by pStream - but how??

End Sub
```

Is there any way to call an instance method of a type of which VBA doesn't have any type information?

I'm not well-versed in C++ / lower level languages, so I'm not quite sure how and where interface functions are represented in memory, but maybe there's some way to get a function pointer (GetProcAddr maybe?) and invoke this (CreateTread?) somehow? Appreciate any ideas!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two big problems here.

First, in VBA, `Set something = Nothing` is what you'd do to call `IUnknown::Release` on the object. But you have a pointer, not something known to the VBA, so you can't use it like an object.

Once you've went with pointers, you must go with the pointers all the way. You really can't just go "I wanna use it like an object but I wanna a pointer sometime".

The next problem is that because you got a pointer, you are now limited in VBA with what you can do with it. VBA cannot have a `Declare` statement that references namespace scoped functions like `IUnknown::Release` -- that basically belongs to a class, and can't be called directly from a `Declare` statement because you need to have an instance and do a offset from it. But you can't go to the offset, say "let's run whatever is there" in VBA, either.

You *might* be able to use CopyMemory API to copy the pointer to a `Object` variable, but I really don't recommend this since it usually ends in crashes, heartbreaks and tears.

In short, I believe we have a XY problem here. Instead of asking on how to do `IUnknown::Release` in VBA, why don't you state what you are actually trying to solve? There might be an easier solution that doesn't involve all those API messes.

Comment: That is unfortunate! I've seen examples of running assembly in VBA directly etc., so have a feeling this would be possible to solve in theory - but maybe so complex that it doesn't make sense (or would get blocked by most AV software anyway) ..
In my case, I'm building an IPC framework where Excel communicates with another process. Part of that is e.g. marshaling COM references across processes, so calling CoMarshalInterface(), which needs to write to an IStream, which in turns means I need to create a stream first - could not find any VBA-known ones for that (ADO's stream didn't work)

Comment: Sounds to me that you're dealing with low level COM components that are not necessarily VBA-firendly . In this case, you need to consider using an external DLL where you have the free to do what you do and expose the methods you need to invoke/pass in to the VBA. That would be simpler and much more maintainable, I think.

Comment: Can't disagree; I'm still torn between VBA, or a proper XLL - latter would make these kind of things a breeze of course, but comes with its own downsides in my particular use case.. anyways, appreciate your input. Didn't know Set obj = Nothing in VBA calls IUnknown::Release. I've modified CreateStreamOnHGlobal third parameter to be a ByRef stream as stdole.IUnknown and release it; this seems to work well in that particular case. (Will leave question open for a few days though, as in principle calling other interface methods, not just Release, may be interesting as well)

Comment: Hm. That's clever. I'm cuffed I didn't think of that. If the interface also implements IDispatch, you may be able to call other methods using latebinding with a `Object` variable since that'll go through the IDispatch::Invoke and thus not rely on you knowing the interface at compile time. If It does not implement IDispatch, then I would not expect it to work for unknown interfaces.

Comment: Thanks! That's very interesting regarding IDispatch - I'd assume most objects in question don't implement this (e.g. the IStream return by SHCreateMemStream would be interesting) - but only one way to find out ... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use copy memory to dereference the object pointer to access the IStream Object vtable - this is an array of function pointers for each of the methods of the class. You can then use pointer offsets and DispCallFunc to invoke the functions in the vtable passing necessary arguments.

This technique works for all COM objects.

Several people have created wrapper functions to make this process easier. I have used some techniques here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/274532/146810

This is my wrapper library for calling vtable functions of com objects.

https://github.com/Greedquest/CodeReviewFiles/tree/master/VBAHack/COMToolsSrc

(As @this points out, IUnknown::Release is a special case and yes you can copy the pointer onto a variable declared as object, then set to nothing to release the pointer)